# Flexible, per user MDC and marker for Java EE logging on JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, jboss, java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I want to implement logging for a larger enterprise application with several services. An important design constraint is the implementation of a logging which implements the approach "log everything". To be as fast as possible, the first idea is to log per node in a cluster into a single log file. With an additional service the logs are fetched and cleared on the node to a central logging service where they can be streamed to analyze the content.

The system will be based on JBoss 7.1 and I want the logger to work via CDI like:

```
@Inject
private MyLogger logger;
...
logger.info("Info message");
...
```

With slf4j for logger creation the class of the instantiating logger is needed (and also wanted for logging). So, the injection can be produced within a producer class like:

```
@Produces
public MyLogger create(InjectionPoint ip) {
    return new MyLogger(ip.getBean().getBeanClass());
}
```

Within MyLogger the actual logger is created via:

```
public MyLogger(Class<?> clazz) {
    super();
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
}
```

MyLogger is than a simple delegate to the slf4j logger implementing the typical methods like trace, debug, info, warn and error. The delegate can also be enhanced to support markers. Up to this point, everything is good.

The last issues and the point of this question is how I can implement MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) to be supported not per thread, but per session/user... I am worried since slf4j's MDC only works per thread, I get the wrong information and I also want to set the information in several places independently.

The idea was to implement an own MDC stateful bean. This bean can be filled independently  by other stateful beans like user login, application state changing beans, processing information and so forth. This bean could look like that:

```
@Stateful
public class MappedDiagnosticContext {

    private final Map<String, String> contextInformation = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void addConextInformation(String type, String value) {
        contextInformation.put(type, value);
    }

    public void removeConextInformation(String type) {
        contextInformation.remove(type);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getContextMap() {
        return contextInformation;
    }
}
```

What I now need is to get access for MyLogger to the stateful bean to do something like that within MyLogger:

```
...
@EJB
private MappedDiagnosticContext mappedDiagnosticContext;
...
public final void info(String infoMessage) {
    MDC.setContextMap(mappedDiagnosticContext.getContextMap());
    logger.info(infoMessage);
    MDC.clear();
}
...
```

The EJB inject obviously does not work due to getLogger(clazz) usage in the producer class. The questions are now:

- Can I use

  @EJB
  private MappedDiagnosticContext mappedDiagnosticContext;

in the producer class to get the stateful bean in the correct state? How is the producer class treated? As singleton? I can not test this scenario so easily, so the question might be faster. ;-)

- Is there another way to get my information in place, I cannot see currently? Do I have a chance to access the correct stateful bean in the producer method? If yes, how?
- Is there a free/OpenSource library out there which already has the functionality I need?

I am curious about the answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand on the first read through, but is there a reason why you would inject a logger rather than just use a static Logger?

Comment: It is due to ease of use and (hopefully, somehow) a way to access EJBs via injection. With static loggers it is not possible due to they are not created by the container. If it is possible to use static loggers and to get my context information in that way, I would be happy, too.

Comment: In JBoss AS 7 static loggers are used. They are created in interfaces since it uses JBoss Logging for i18n capabilities, https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/blob/master/controller/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/controller/ControllerLogger.java#L59. You could easily just create a static logger interface or class.

Comment: There are two issues with that: 1) It is strictly JBoss, which is not what I really want. I want to stick as close to JavaEE 6 as possible to keep the system portable. 2) How do I get my stateful information for the current logged in user, for example?

Comment: Right, you could do that with any logging framework really. And slf4j isn't Java EE 6 either, just saying :-) Yeah, that definitely won't work per user. That would be a tough one to do I would think.